# how to auto populate the contents of a tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to auto populate the contents of my tinymce, this will be done in certain scenarios. I tried doing some console testing to see what jquery function will work on it.

I tried:

```
$("#tinymce").text("test");
$("#tinymce").html("test");
$("#tinymce").val("test");
```

But they all returned this error:

> VM3476:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function
>       at :1:15

```
 <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('htmleditor1').onLoad.dispatch();" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" data-gramm_id="e2122774-06e2-55e3-4d20-705ac5c51517" data-gramm="true" data-gramm_editor="true">
<g class="gr_ gr_3 gr-alert gr_spell gr_run_anim ContextualSpelling ins-del multiReplace" id="3" data-gr-id="3">sadasd</g><br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If after tinyMCE init**

You must use setContent() method, so to set full content

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('My test!');
```

or if you wanna change only selected section

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');
```

**If before tinyMCE init**

You could set directly your HTML container

```
$('textarea').text('My text!');
```